# How to go to AWS RDS instance for some work in the directory of RDS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I want to directly work in the AWS RDS Server (MYSQL).
All I can find is to use mysql client.
But I literally want to work on the RDS server like

```
SSH user@{rds ip}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you wanting to do on the 'server'?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to deal with binary log using mysqlbinlog utility in the sever

Comment: Ah! You should have mentioned this in your question. See: [Accessing MySQL binary logs - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.MySQL.Binarylog.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon RDS is a **fully-managed database service**.

You only have access to the Amazon RDS management console, Amazon RDS API calls (that can launch/stop instances, take snapshots, etc) and the SQL endpoint.

You do not have access to the 'server', nor are you given full 'superuser' permissions when connecting to the SQL endpoint.